# htmlとjqueryで入力フォームを作成、ページが呼び出されるごとに「No」の箇所に自動採番したい

Tags: html, jquery

以下の形で、各項目を作成して入力フォームが呼び出せれます。
この呼び出された際に、一番上の「NO」に、呼び出されるごとに　１、２、３、・・・・・・と受付番号を採番していきたいのですが、何かよい方法があれば教えてほしいです。

htmlやjquery初心者なので検索方法がいまいちピントこないです。宜しくお願いします。

```
<!-- 基本情報入力 -->
<div id='inputPage'>
<table>
<tr><!-- NO -->
<th>NO</th>
<td><body onLoad="startFunc()"></body></td>
</tr>
<tr><!-- 氏名 -->
<th>氏名<span class='req-mark'>必須</span></th>
<td><input type="text" name="inName" class="inName" placeholder="例) 矢崎　一郎"></td>
</tr>
<tr><!-- 生年月日 -->
<th>生年月日<span class='req-mark'>必須</span></th>
<td><input type="text" name="inBirthday" class="inBirthday" placeholder="例)19850101"></td>
</tr>
<tr><!-- 性別 -->
<th>性別<span class='req-mark'>必須</span></th>
<td><input type="radio" name="inSex" class="inSex" value="男">男<input type="radio" name="inSex" class="inSex" value="女">女</td>
</tr>
<tr><!-- 住所 -->
<th>住所</th>
<td><text>郵便番号、もしくは現住所のどちらかをご入力ください。</text>
<label for="inPostalCode">郵便番号：</label><input type="text" name="inPostalCode" class="PostalCode" placeholder="例)1112222">
<label for="inAddress">現住所：</label><input type="text" name="inAddress" class="inAddress" placeholder="例)〇〇県○○市or〇〇区">
</td>
</tr>
<tr><!-- 緊急連絡先 -->
<th>緊急連絡先<span class='req-mark'>必須</span></th>
<td><input type="tel" name="inTelNumber" class="inTelNumber" placeholder="例)0312345678" max="11"></td>
</tr>
<tr><!-- 得意な事 -->
<th>得意な事<span class='req-mark'>必須</span></th>
<td><select class="inSkill">
        <option value="土木">土木</option>
        <option value="清掃">清掃</option>
        <option value="料理">料理</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr><!-- 交通経路 -->
<th>交通経路<span class='req-mark'>必須</span></th>
<td><select class="inUse">
        <option value="軽トラック">軽トラック</option>
        <option value="バン">バン</option>
        <option value="軽車両">軽車両</option>
        <option value="電車">電車</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr><!-- メールアドレス -->
<th>メールアドレス</th>
<td><input type="email" name="inMail" class="inMail" placeholder="例)yazaki@gmail.com">
<label for="inPostalCode">応援依頼の対応可否：</label>
<input type="radio" name="checkRes" class="response" value="yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="checkRes" class="response" value="no">No
</td>
</tr>
<tr><!-- 車両情報 -->
<th>車両情報</th>
<td><select class="inCar">
        <option value="軽トラック">軽トラック</option>
        <option value="バン">バン</option>
        <option value="軽車両">軽車両</option>
        <option value="etc">etc</option>
    </select><br></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="showCenter">
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="showBtn" value="QRコード作成" /><br>
        <text style='text-align:center;color:red;font-size:small;'>※ボタンを押すと端末に画像が自動保存されます。</text>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 「各項目を作成して入力フォームが呼び出せれます」私にはこの部分の理解がちょっと難しかったです。例えば画面の一番下に「＋」ボタンが表示されていてそれを押すと上記の入力フォームが増えていくイメージでしょうか？

Comment: URLをクリックすると、入力画面に飛ぶので、そのタイミングで採番したいです。

Comment: サーバサイドの言語（PHPやrubyやpython等）やデータ管理（RDBSやNoSQLやファイル管理）は利用せず。ということですか？

Comment: はいそうです。。。

Answer (score 1):

フロントエンド（HTMLとjavascript）だけで完全な採番を実現することは難しいでしょう。

一般的な採番とは
被りなく、決まった連番で提供する必要がありますが,

HTMLとjQUeryだけでは、ほかの人がどんだけアクセスしているかはわかりえません。

通常採番を実現するには
サーバ側でスクリプト言語とデータベースなどを利用して、
アクセスがあった場合にカウントアップするという方式を利用します。

カウントアップするためにはサーバに中央集権でデータを保存する必要があるのでフロントエンドだけでの実現は難しいでしょう。

例えば、かぶりづらいようにランダムで文字を表示するとかはできますが、それでも全く被らないかといわれると理論上は難しいでしょう。

フォームを利用しているということは、サーバサイドの利用もありそうですので、サーバサイドで実装することを考えたほうがよろしいでしょう。